# how to apply time series model on spark streaming data

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, time-series, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

In my Application, i need to receive the streaming data from **kafka** and need to apply **timeseries** model on received streaming data in Spark.

I was able to read the streaming data from kafka, but i am not aware how to apply **timeseries** model on streaming data.

Anyone please suggest me how **timeseries** works and usecases.

**Dataset:**

```
725030:14732,2008,01,01,00,5.0,-3.9,1020.4,270,4.6,2,0.0,0.0
725030:14732,2008,01,01,01,5.0,-3.3,1020.6,290,4.1,2,0.0,0.0
725030:14732,2008,01,01,02,5.0,-3.3,1020.0,310,3.1,2,0.0,0.0
725030:14732,2008,01,01,03,4.4,-2.8,1020.1,300,1.5,2,0.0,0.0
725030:14732,2008,01,01,04,3.3,-4.4,1020.5,240,2.6,0,0.0,0.0
```

**Sparkjava code is given below:**

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;

import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;
import scala.Tuple2;

//KafkatoSparkStreaming Working Code
/*this code is converting KafkaToSparkstreaming into DataSet by useing SparkJava
 * */
public class a {
    public static  void main(String arr[]) throws InterruptedException
    {


        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.set("spark.app.name", "SparkReceiver"); //The name of application. This will appear in the UI and in log data.
        //conf.set("spark.ui.port", "7077");    //Port for application's dashboard, which shows memory and workload data.
        conf.set("dynamicAllocation.enabled","false");  //Which scales the number of executors registered with this application up and down based on the workload
        //conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost"); //Cassandra Host Adddress/IP
        conf.set("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");  //For serializing objects that will be sent over the network or need to be cached in serialized form.
        conf.setMaster("local");
        conf.set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true");

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        // Create the context with 2 seconds batch size
        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(2000));

        Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

        kafkaParams.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181"); //Make all kafka data for this cluster appear under a particular path. 
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "testgroup");   //String that uniquely identifies the group of consumer processes to which this consumer belongs
        kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092"); //Producer can find a one or more Brokers to determine the Leader for each topic.
        kafkaParams.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder"); //Serializer to use when preparing the message for transmission to the Broker.
        kafkaParams.put("request.required.acks", "1");  //Producer to require an acknowledgement from the Broker that the message was received.

        Set<String> topics = Collections.singleton("ny-2008.csv");

        //Create an input DStream for Receiving data from socket
        JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
                String.class, 
                String.class, 
                StringDecoder.class, 
                StringDecoder.class, 
                kafkaParams, topics);

        //Create JavaDStream<String>
        JavaDStream<String> msgDataStream = directKafkaStream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
              return tuple2._2();
            }
          });
        //Create JavaRDD<Row>
        msgDataStream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
              @Override
              public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) { 
                  JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = rdd.map(new Function<String, Row>() {
                      @Override
                      public Row call(String msg) {
                        Row row = RowFactory.create(msg);
                        return row;
                      }
                    });
        //Create Schema       
        StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {DataTypes.createStructField("Message", DataTypes.StringType, true)});
        //Get Spark 2.0 session       
        SparkSession spark = JavaSparkSessionSingleton.getInstance(rdd.context().getConf());
        Dataset<Row> msgDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);
        msgDataFrame.show();
        msgDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("weatherTemporaryData");
        msgDataFrame.select("280").show();



              }
        });

        ssc.start();            
        ssc.awaitTermination();  
    }

}

class JavaSparkSessionSingleton {
      private static transient SparkSession instance = null;
      public static SparkSession getInstance(SparkConf sparkConf) {
        if (instance == null) {
          instance = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .config(sparkConf)
            .getOrCreate();
        }
        return instance;
      }
    }
```

Comment: What's _"timeseries model"_? What's _"apply timeseries model"_?

Comment: aggregate them over time. for example every 24 hours, every 48 hours or every week. or something which makes sense to your data.it is time series model.

Answer (score 0):

In a statistical point of view, a timeseries model uses a time shifting window. For example you will try to predict a future value from N past values. If this is what you are trying to achieve, you should have a look to Window functions. Jacek wrote a good issue on this : [Window Aggregate Operators](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-windows.html).

In short and to help you understand what is going on, you will have to create a WindowSpec instance to specify :

- A partition scheme, based for example on logged event classes
- A local order in partitions, in your case the event timestamp

Then you will use the [`lag`](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-functions.html#lag) function to get events that happened before a given event.

For timeseries model inference, you must be carefull to stationarity because consecutive events are not independant. In some situation you could achieve better stationarity by differencing (it eliminates the trend) ; you will not consider the event values but their difference with the preceding event - the `lag` function will be your friend again, but you will need N+1 values.

Once you have done differencing and laging, you can try to apply any Spark ML library statistical modeling method.